# Using the filters i choose i want to filter my json array so that only those rows will be displayed

Tags: javascript, html

so far this is what i have done

```
 <div class="dropdown">
            <p class="filter-text">LANGUAGE</p>
                <select class="selection" name="language" multiple id="lang">
                    <option value="CH">Chinese</option>
                    <option value="EN">English</option>
                    <option value="JP">Japanese</option>
                </select>
</div>
```

js:

```
`$("#language :selected").map(function ( i, el ) {
            var values = $(el).val();
            console.log(values);
            // customfilter(values);
});
function custonfilter(){
....//HELP//
}`
```

My json is coming from an ajax request and looks like:

```
 var json=[{marketName: "Asia",language:english},
{marketName: "Asia",language:chinese},{marketName: "Asia",language:japanese},
…}]
```

So, when user checks on english my new json shud contain all rows with language=english.

Comment: You have the order of the parameters incorrect inside the map function. its `array.map(function(currentValue, index...)`, you are interpreting the second parameter as the element, when in fact its the index.